# why is getline() not working in my little experiment?

Tags: c++, string, input, lambda, getline

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Capture a lambda with a lambda and use it in the lambda it's //
    // captured in along with some code in the lambda that captures //
    // it.                                                          //
    //                                                              //
    // Add to that to capture a variable in the client and use that //
    // too.                                                         //
    //                                                              //
    // Then make a lambda that captures a class object and calls    //
    // some method or methods with it, optionally modifies the re-  //
    // sult...                                                      //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Note: std::function<type(type)> f;                           //
    // f = <define lambda here>                                     //
    // f() //calls lambda                                           //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    #include <functional>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::function;
    using std::getline;
    using std::string;

    class Experimental {
       private:
          int x;
          string s;
       public:
          Experimental() {}
          ~Experimental() {}
          void set_x(int new_x);
          int get_x();
          void set_s(string s_in);
          string get_s();
    };

    void Experimental::set_x(int new_x) {
       x = new_x;
    }

    int Experimental::get_x() {
       return (x);
    }

    void Experimental::set_s(string s_in) {
       s = s_in;
    }

    string Experimental::get_s() {
       return s;
    }

    int main() {
       double n;
       string input;
       Experimental* experiment = new Experimental();

       cout << "Enter a number: ";
       cin >> n;

       function<double(double)> f;
       f = [&f](double k) {
          return (k ? k * f(k-1) : 1);
       };

       function<double(double)> g;
       g = [&f,n](double m) {
          return (f(n)/n);
       };

       function<int()> T1; //capture a class and do stuff...
       T1 = [&experiment,n]() {
          experiment->set_x(13 + n);
          int m = experiment->get_x();
          return (m);
       };

       function<string(string)> T2; //capture a class and do stuff...
       T2 = [&experiment](const string in) {
          experiment->set_s(in);
          string s = experiment->get_s();
          return (s);
       };

       cout << "The factorial of " << n << " is: ";
       cout << f(n) << endl;

       cout << "The factorial of " << n << " divided by " << n << " is: ";
       cout << g(n) << endl;

       cout << "The new value of x in experiment is: ";
       cout << T1() << endl;

       cout << "Enter a string: ";
       getline(cin, input); //FIXME
    cout << "input is: " << input << "<-" << endl;

       cout << "The new string in experiment is: ";
       cout << T2(input) << endl;
       delete experiment;

       return (0);
    }
```

I know it's ugly. Not reeally using lambdas as they're meant to be used while I experiment here at first. For some reason I'm not getting input for my string variable and I don't know why. Can someone help/ point out what the problem is?

Comment: Why paste a lot ugly lines when the FIXME concern only one? You could remove 98% of your post

Comment: Yeah, I know, my code is ugly. I'm sorry, I'm trying to learn  :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `getline` is reading the end-of-line left in the buffer after:

```
cin >> n;
```

Fix that by using [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
#include <limits>
...
  cin >> n;
  ...
  cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  getline(cin, input);
```

Comment: Then getline() acts like cin (ie: stops at the first space entered). So if I enter multi word string with spaces in it I only get the first word.

Comment: No it doesn't, it reads a whole line. (You need to insert that `ignore`  just before you read the line, not sure if that was clear in my answer.)

Comment: My bad, it's late and I'm getting pretty tired. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common error, basically you have

```
cin >> number;
getline(cin, str);
```

Now think about this (you seem a good programmer so I'm only giving you a clue). How many newlines are contained in a number? How many newlines will `cin >> number;` actually read?

Comment: Seems to me it would read only one. I had this problem when learning c (now I'm messing w/ c++). In c that '\n' in the buffer just massacred me every time. Never did learn ways to deal with it and often forget to think of it as the source of the problem.

what I ended up using from Mat suggestion was: "cin.ignore(1, '\n');" Seems to work.

Comment: It reads zero, there are no newlines in a number. One way to think about this is to remember that cin works exactly like reading from a file. If you were reading from a file you wouldn't expect reading a number to automatically move on to the next line. Reading from cin doesn't either. Even though you have *typed* a newline it hasn't been *read*.

Comment: `cin.ignore(1, '\n');` only works if the newline is the only unread character. Imagine you typed number <space> <newline> then you would only ignore the space and the newline would still be there. Mat's way is the right way.